# How to use Google API to send all draft emails

Tags: google-api

I am new for Google API.

I need to know how to use the Google API to send all drafted mails. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using the Gmail API   [Users.drafts: send](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)) from Google Apps Script will help you in sending the draft mails.

Also check,
[GmailMessage.forward](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object))  method . Hope, it will help you out!